# Regex exclude ":" and a whitespace if they exist

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a regex here:

```
var text = new Regex(@"(?<=Paybacks).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This looks for the line where it starts with Paybacks. Now it currently prints ": blah".
The context sometimes can be "Paybacks" or "Paybacks:" or "Paybacks " or I don't know "Paybacks (with thousands of whitespaces). How can I modify this regex to be like.. after "Paybacks" ignore a colon and a whitespace (or whitespaces) that may or may not exist.

I've been playing with it in regex101 and this seems to be working, but is there a better way?

```
(?<=Volatility(:\s)).*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these situations, you'd better use a regex with a capturing group:

```cs
var pattern = new Regex(@"Paybacks[\s:]*(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then, you can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Match(text, pattern)?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Paybacks%5B%5Cs%3A%5D*%28.*%29&i=Paybacks%3A%20blah%0D%0APaybacks%3Ablah%0D%0APaybacks%20blah&o=x):

[image]

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/W9tZL5):

```cs
var texts = new List<string> { "Paybacks: blah","Paybacks:blah","Paybacks blah"};
var pattern = new Regex(@"Paybacks[\s:]*(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
texts.ForEach(text => Console.WriteLine(pattern.Match(text)?.Groups[1].Value));
```

printing 3 `blah`s.

Answer (score 2):

You might also match optional colons and whitspace chars in the lookbehind, and start matching the first chars being any non whitspace char other than `:`

```
(?<=Paybacks[:\s]*)[^\s:].*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `Paybacks` Match literally
  - `[:\s]*` Optionally match either `:` or a whitespace char using a character class
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^\s:].*` Match a single non whitespace char other than `:` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CIKwrK/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/bBclvV)

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=Paybacks[:\s]*)[^\s:].*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] strings = {"Paybacks: blah", "Paybacks blah", "Paybacks                  blah"};

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(s)?.Value);
}
```

Output

```
blah
blah
blah
```

---

If the order should be a single optional colon and optional whitespace chars, you can make the colon optional and the quantifier for the whitespace chars 0 or more using `:?\s*`

```
(?<=Paybacks:?\s*)[^\s:].*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/15NZ6i/1)